# How can I use the Gazebo Garden Profiler to get performance information about individual plugins?

Tags: gazebo, ros2, simulation, performance

I am using **gz garden** to simulate a complex robot consisting of multiple components. I have already simplified with **primitives** the **collision meshes**, played with **max_contacts** but I keep getting low **RTF** (below 50%) and I would like to understand if any of the custom plugins I have written have problems or not.

**How can I get data regarding the performance of the individual plugin (threads, memory, etc...) when I start my demo?**

I saw on the documentation that a Profiler is available but I still don't see how it can be used with Gz garden.

**Physics Settings**

```
<physics type='ode' default='true'>
            <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
            <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
            <real_time_update_rate>0.0</real_time_update_rate>
            <max_contacts>2</max_contacts>
            <ode>
                <solver>
                    <thread_position_correction>1</thread_position_correction>
                    <island_threads>10</island_threads>
                </solver>
            </ode>
        </physics>
```

My distro is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I'm working with Ros 2 Humble.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Gazebo Classic instructions](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=profiler&cat=tools_utilities) are also valid for Gazebo Sim, as since Gazebo 11 the 'gz-common profiler' is used for both.

For Garden, you will have to interpret those instructions somewhat due to the rename of Ignition (ign) back to Gazebo (gz).

See also [these official instructions](https://gazebosim.org/api/common/5/profiler.html) for Garden.

Comment: Thanks, I found the CMakeLists.txt option and I'll try to enable it properly:

https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/b8d16797ef134db95c34343f445d8e56e9a9159f/CMakeLists.txt#L27